# C++ Compiler uses the wrong Costmap2DROS version

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d-ros, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to write some c++ code that uses the Costmap2DROS class, but I have this error at compile time:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::Costmap2DROS(std::__cxx11::string&, tf2_ros::Buffer&)

/opt/ros/kinetic/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h:80:3: note: candidate: costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::Costmap2DROS(std::__cxx11::string, tf::TransformListener&)
   Costmap2DROS(std::string name, tf::TransformListener& tf);
```

The line that gives the problem is this one:

```
costmap = new costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS("global_planner", tfl);
```

where tfl is a tf2::Buffer& object.

I have seen from these reference pages
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2DROS.html

http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2DROS.html
that depending on the ROS version you have different constructors for the class.
The problem is that I am working on ROS Kinetic, that according to the ROS wiki, uses the melodic version, so why my compiler is using the jade one?
How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303391/c++-compiler-uses-the-wrong-costmap2dros-version/) by [SteBisi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32697/stebisi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2DROS.html), in ROS kinetic the constructor for the Costmap is the following

`Costmap2DROS (std::string name, tf::TransformListener &tf)`

From your error message your ros distro is kinetic, not jade or melodic, so you should go with this one (which in this particular case it's equal to the jade one).

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2018-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SteBisi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32697/stebisi/) on 2018-09-15**:
Thank you. My bad, I misread the references